# Min validation not working in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema in which the balance field is declared as shown below

```
balance: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    default: 30
}
```

I have set 0 as minimum value so that the balance would not be a negative value. But when I decrement the balance value through update query, balance turns out to be a negative value.

My update query:

```
User.update({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
}, {
    $inc: {
        balance: -10
    }
}, function(error, result) {
    // code
});
```

Did I make any mistake with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose validation is an internal middleware which is not called on update; if you want to enforce validations on update, you should find the document, update the attributes, and save it.

For example:

```
User.findById(id, function(err, result) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);
  user.balance = -10;
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    ...
  });
});
```

Comment: This is not actually answering the question, but rather giving an alternative that for some cases might work, but not always.

Answer (score 5):

By default mongoose does not validate on an update call, however there is an option for this. Look at the mongoose documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html (Update Validators)

```
var opts = { runValidators: true };
Toy.update({}, { color: 'bacon' }, opts, function (err) {
  assert.equal(err.errors.color.message,
    'Invalid color');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers actually answer the question.

I came up against this and even with the runValidators flag - Mongoose will not validate on some operations. As below

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-only-run-for-some-operations

> One final detail worth noting: update validators only run on the following update operators:
>
> $set
>
> $unset
>
> $push (>= 4.8.0)
>
> $addToSet (>= 4.8.0)
>
> $pull (>= 4.12.0)
>
> $pullAll (>= 4.12.0)
>
> For instance, the below update will succeed, regardless of the value of number, because update validators ignore $inc.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling validation on update (which is disabled by default) using `findByIdAndUpdate` would look like this:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {
  $set: attributes,
}, {
  new: true,
  runValidators: true,
})
.then((user) => {
  if (!user) {
    // user not found
  }

  console.log(user);
})
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```